# How to construct observable kinematic maps in R ? I have data in form of hdf5 file

Tags: r, kinematics

`install.packages("hdf5r")`

> install.packages("hdf5r")
> `library(hdf5r)`
> #In my case h5read function is not working it’s giving an error
> `data <- h5read("filename.hdf5", "dataset_name")`

## how will I get to know the dataset_name ?

> `x <- data$variable1`
> `y <- data$variable2`
>
> `library(ggplot2)`
> `ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + labs(x = "Variable 1", y = "Variable 2", title = "Kinematic Map)`